# I have conducted a Chi-Squared test in R, and want to know how to display observed vs expected values in a barplot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, chi-squared-test, graphical-model, barplot

Essentially I have my data, and easily calucalated the chi-squared statistic. Now I have this, I want to create a bar plot with my observed values beside the expected, for the relevant groups.

I tried using barplot(x2$observed, x2$expected) but this produces a mosaic plot? Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: This isn't my image- but I want to create something similar using the chi-squared results I have calculated.]

Comment: As I say in my answer, I think the problem here is a confusion about what a barplot is and what a mosaic plot is, so I vote to leave it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code:

```
M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"),
                    party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))

(Xsq <- chisq.test(M))  # Prints test summary

barplot(Xsq$observed, Xsq$expected, beside = TRUE)
```

and got a barplot very similar to the one you posted. This is a barplot and not a mosaic plot.

If you wanted a mosaic plot you would use:

```
attach(M)
mosaicplot(~party + gender, data = M)
```

I think the issue here is a confusion about what a barplot is and what a mosaic plot is, not about R code.